# Data set for Q & A system training

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, dataset

What is the standard (or just good) open data set to train a model for question answering? Ideally, not only in English.

Thanks!

Comment: This is probably a better fit at [OpenData](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/)